# How do I add a new verb to my FB frictionless share app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, sharing, social-media

If I have an app that already does frictionless sharing to FB using an open graph verb, can I add another verb to the app without requiring users to explicitly grant permissions for the new verb?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The only permission you need from the users is "publish_actions", and you already have that.

I think this is might be a bit of a problem, because the Auth Dialog now shows what actions can be posted by the app, and you don't see a new Auth Dialog when those actions have been changed. We'll probably see this exploited in some way, and then end up with yet another confirmation dialog to add some friction to the frictionless sharing.

Comment: The actions are approved by Facebook, so it shouldn't really be possible to bait-and-switch like that - if you get something reasonable and sensible approved then try to add something crappy and spammy you'll likely not get the second one approved - also, the regular spam systems for stream posting also run on open graph actions so there's that to think about too